# Is it possible to polyfill abstract constructors?

Tags: typescript

I find myself in need to run the following on TypeScript 3.9.6.

```
export type Class<
    _CtorArgs extends any[] = any[],
    InstanceType = {},
    StaticType = {},
    _IsAbstract = false
> = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
```

However I'm getting

```
dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:15 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
                 ~~~

dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:20 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
                      ~~~

dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:33 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;


dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:34 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
                                    ~

dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:36 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
                                      ~~

dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:51 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
                                                     ~

dir/polyfills/mixin-polyfill/types.d.ts:40:53 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

40 > = (abstract new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType) & StaticType;
```

Is there a way to polyfill this sort of thing for 3.9.6?

Comment: *Why* are you on 3.9.6?

Comment: A good question, for another time unfortunately.